# WPF application Linq to sql getting data

Tags: sql, wpf, linq

I'm making a WPF application with a datagrid that displays some sql data.
Now i'm making a search field but that doesn't seem to work:

- Contactpersoon is an nvarchar
- bedrijf is an nvarchar
  but
- LeverancierPK is an INT 
  How can I combinate that in my search?
  If i convert LeverancierPK to string, then I can use Contains but that gives me an error

  ```
      //Inisiatie
      PRCEntities vPRCEntities = new PRCEntities();

      var vFound = from a in vPRCEntities.tblLeveranciers
                   where ((((a.LeverancierPK).ToString()).Contains(vWoord)) ||
                         (a.Contactpersoon.Contains(vWoord)) ||
                         (a.Bedrijf.Contains(vWoord)))
                   orderby a.LeverancierPK
                   select a;
      myDataGrid_Leveranciers.ItemsSource = vFound;
  ```

Thanks

Comment: Calling contains on a number doesn't make much sense. Consider if vWoord = 12. Are you expecting for the PK of 2123 to match that? I suspect you want `a.LeverancierPK.ToString() == vWoord` here.

Comment: If vWoord = 12 then PK 2123 should match. I know that It doesn't make sence but this doesn't work also:    
                    var vFound = from a in vPRCEntities.tblLeveranciers
                         where ((((a.LeverancierPK == vWoord) ||
                               (a.Contactpersoon.Contains(vWoord)) ||
                               (a.Bedrijf.Contains(vWoord)))
                         orderby a.LeverancierPK
                         select a;

Thanks

Comment: That won't work because LeverancierPK is an int and vWoord is a string. What error are you getting with the .ToString.Contains() option?

Comment: {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: Are you sure LeverancierPK is an integer in your EF model? Have you tried simply `a.LeverancierPK.Contains(vWoord)`?

Comment: Yes its an Int32. If i try a.LeverancierPK.Contains(vWoord) then i get error: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about pulling all records back from the DB (which in your answer you pulled everything back), then you can just do a `.ToList()` before the where clause.

```
var vFound = vPRCEntities.tblLeveranciers.ToList()
             .Where(a => a.LeverancierPK.ToString().Contains(vWoord)) ||
                   a.Contactpersoon.Contains(vWoord) ||
                   a.Bedrijf.Contains(vWoord))
             .OrderBy(a.LeverancierPK);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can do what I was looking for but I think it could be alot shorter.

```
            PRCEntities vPRCEntities = new PRCEntities();

        var vFound = from a in vPRCEntities.tblLeveranciers
                     orderby a.LeverancierPK
                     select a;

        myDataGrid_Leveranciers.ItemsSource = null;
        myDataGrid_Leveranciers.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var item in vFound)
        {
            if (item.Bedrijf.Contains(vWoord))
            {
                myDataGrid_Leveranciers.Items.Add(item);                    
            }
            else
            {           
                if (item.LeverancierPK.ToString().Contains(vWoord))
                {
                    myDataGrid_Leveranciers.Items.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.Contactpersoon != null)
                    {
                        if (item.Contactpersoon.Contains(vWoord))
                        {
                            myDataGrid_Leveranciers.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
```